# mouse click always on ondown mode

Tags: windows, mouse

I have a big problem, and i don't know if it is a hardware or software problem.

I'm on a laptop, and i can't click on anything because mouse it's always on pressing mode. I'm on vista business.

Do you have any advices for me? How can I detect the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try any Live CD/DVD like Knoppix. If the problem exists there too, it's probably a hardware problem. If you have no warranty left on your device you could try to open it and clean the affected contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel > Folder Options

[image]

Change to **Double-click to open and item (single click to select)**

Comment: hm, can't see how this helps?

Comment: if single click is enabled, you lost 'click to select' which can be interpreted as the mouse being "always on pressing mode", you select by hovering over an item, not clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your mouse driver to the latest version.